# How to manage versions and compatibility when publishing a library in .NET

Tags: .net, deployment, dll

I manage a library project that exposes a range of interfaces and library classes.  Our user base is expanding and we want to adopt a more frequent release cycle.  How do I avoid forcing my users needing to recompile every time I release?

Answer (score 2):

Deploy to the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx), manage your publisher redirect policies.

Assemblies in the GAC (can) have their own release cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If your interfaces are changing in each release, then there is no way to avoid your users from recompiling the code. But by using some practices, you may lessen this re-compilation process:

1. Hide the details of your library as much as you can to your users.
2. Try to lessen the dependency of your exported stuff, as much as you can.
3. Do not put too much services in a single interface. Cut your interfaces properly.

Comment: Interfaces should be remaining fairly static.  The parts that may vary are the support library that is released alongside the interfaces.